# почему не работает сохранение в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textxt;

    private Save_Json_av sv = new Save_Json_av();

    public decimal money = 0m;


    void Awake()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("sv_1"))
        {
            sv = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save_Json_av>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sv_1"));
            money = sv.money;
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        textxt.text = money + "";   
    }

    public void KrClick()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            money += 0.000000002m;
        }
    }

    public void KrClick2()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            money += 0.10m;
 
        }
    }
    private void OnApplicationPause()
    {
        Save();
    }
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        Save();
    }
    private void Save()
    {
        sv.money = money;  
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("sv_1", JsonUtility.ToJson(sv));
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
 
}
[Serializable]
public class Save_Json_av
{
    public decimal money;
}
```

Comment: я не смог найти в вашем коде причины несохранения, попробуйте включить отладку и убедитесь что значение money изменяется

Comment: может ли быть это из-за версии юнити?

Comment: попробуйте включить отладку и убедитесь что значение money изменяется